# Find the toggle state of my toggle slide for insert this in the DB

Tags: jquery, find, toggle

i will to find the state of my toggle slide (on the right side) for the insert or update post this in the DB. I need this for customer seetings.

How can i solve this?

This is what i have now:

```
jQuery('.menu_filter').find('.toggle-slide').eq(0).click(function(){
        jQuery('.dark_red_gradient').stop(true,true).toggle();
    });
```

this is my testsite:

http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/report-overview_test.html

Hope someone have idea.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you change a 'id' state between 1 and 0 to show the toggle status.

```
        var X=$(this).attr('id');
        if(X==1){
            $(this).attr('id', '0'); 
        } else {
            $(this).attr('id', '1');
        }
```

Something like this maybe?
Hope it helps.